# Rails: edit path for nested attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to make an app with Rails 4 and Simple Form.

I have 3 models: project, project_question and project_answer.

The associations are:
Project.rb:

```
  has_many :project_questions, dependent: :destroy#, through: :projects
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :project_questions
```

project question:

```
belongs_to :project#, counter_cache: true
  has_one :project_answer, dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :user
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :project_answer
```

Project answer:

```
  belongs_to :project_questions#, counter_cache: true
  belongs_to :user
```

The routes are:

```
  resources :projects do
    resources :project_questions do
      resources :project_answers
    end
  end
```

In my project questions view partial, I try to show the project answer. If the project creator is the current user, I want to put a link to edit the answer. I've tried at least 10 variations on the path and I still can't figure out how to link to the edit project_answer path.

My routes for project answer are:

```
project_project_question_project_answers GET      /projects/:project_id/project_questions/:project_question_id/project_answers(.:format)          project_answers#index
                                              POST     /projects/:project_id/project_questions/:project_question_id/project_answers(.:format)          project_answers#create
  new_project_project_question_project_answer GET      /projects/:project_id/project_questions/:project_question_id/project_answers/new(.:format)      project_answers#new
 edit_project_project_question_project_answer GET      /projects/:project_id/project_questions/:project_question_id/project_answers/:id/edit(.:format) project_answers#edit
      project_project_question_project_answer GET      /projects/:project_id/project_questions/:project_question_id/project_answers/:id(.:format)      project_answers#show
                                              PATCH    /projects/:project_id/project_questions/:project_question_id/project_answers/:id(.:format)      project_answers#update
                                              PUT      /projects/:project_id/project_questions/:project_question_id/project_answers/:id(.:format)      project_answers#update
                                              DELETE   /projects/:project_id/project_questions/:project_question_id/project_answers/:id(.:format)      project_answers#destroy
```

My project_question partial is:

```
<div class="containerfluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <% @project.project_questions.each do |singleQuestion| %>

          <div class="categorytitle">
            <%= singleQuestion.title %>

          </div>
          <div class="generaltext">
            <%= singleQuestion.try(:content) %>
          </div>
          <span class="editproject">
            <% if current_user.id == @project.creator_id && singleQuestion.project_answer.try(:answer).blank? %>

                <%= link_to 'Answer this question', new_project_project_question_project_answer_path(:project_id => @project.id, :project_question_id => singleQuestion.id) %>
                <% elsif  %>
                   <% if current_user.id == @project.creator_id  %>

                      <div class="datasubtextq">
                        <%=singleQuestion.project_answer.try(:answer) %>
                        <span class="editproject">
                          <%= link_to 'Edit Answer', [@project_answer.project_question, @project_answer] %>
                        </span>

                      </div>

                <% else  %>
                    <div class="datasubtextq">
                      <%=singleQuestion.project_answer.try(:answer) %>

                    </div>
            <% end %>
                            <% end %>

          </span>
      <% end %>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The line that I'm trying to figure out is:

```
  <%= link_to 'Edit Answer', [@project_answer.project_question, @project_answer] %>
```

I tried this because I found a tutorial at: http://blog.8thcolor.com/en/2011/08/nested-resources-with-independent-views-in-ruby-on-rails/. While the edit example in that blog uses a separate file for my equivalent of answer, I thought maybe changing the order of the objects might help. It didn't.

I have also tried:

```
                      <%= link_to 'Edit Answer',[@project_answer.singleQuestion, @project_answer] %>

                      <%= link_to 'Edit Answer', edit_project_project_question_project_answer_path(@project_answer.singleQuestion, @project_answer) %>

                      <%= link_to 'Edit Answer', edit_project_project_question_project_answer_path(@singleQuestion.project_answer, @project_answer) %>
                      <%= link_to 'Edit Answer', edit_project_project_question_project_answer_path(@project_answer.project_question, @project_answer) %>
```

How do I link to the edit path for project answer when project answer is displayed inside the view partial for project question?

My project_answer controller has:

```
class ProjectAnswersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_project
  before_action :set_project_question
  before_action :set_project_answer, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]


  # GET /project_answers
  # GET /project_answers.json
  def index
    @project_answers = ProjectAnswer.all
  end

  # GET /project_answers/1
  # GET /project_answers/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /project_answers/new


  def new
    @project_answer = @project_question.build_project_answer
  end

  # GET /project_answers/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /project_answers
  # POST /project_answers.json
  def create
    @project_answer = @project_question.build_project_answer(project_answer_params)


    respond_to do |format|
      if @project_answer.save
        format.html { redirect_to @project, notice: 'Project answer was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @project_answer }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @project_answer.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /project_answers/1
  # PATCH/PUT /project_answers/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @project_answer.update(project_answer_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @project_answer, notice: 'Project answer was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @project_answer.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /project_answers/1
  # DELETE /project_answers/1.json
  def destroy
    @project_answer.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to project_answers_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.

    def set_project
      @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
    end

    def set_project_question
      @project_question = @project.project_questions.find(params[:project_question_id])
    end


  def set_project_answer
      @project_answer = ProjectAnswer.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def project_answer_params
      params[:project_answer].permit(:answer, :project_question_id, :id)
    end
end
```

I think there is a clue in the url displayed when I click the link for 'edit answer'. The page itself is blank white. The url is the project/id/project_question/id ONLY. I was expecting the project answer id to be in that line too.

I try typing a url into the url bar that includes project answers and I get a route error (even though the answer is displayed on my show page).

I tried to find the answer in my project console. I get errors that say:

```
p.project_questions.project_answers.find
NoMethodError: undefined method `project_answers' for #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy_ProjectQuestion:0x00000104382e08>
```

I have tried the same search without the pluralised table names.

Comment: Please post your `project_questions_controller`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have defined the @project_answer variable within your form so you can't use it.

You should use...

```
<%= link_to 'Edit Answer', edit_project_project_question_project_answer_path(@project, singleQuestion, singleQuestion.project_answer) %>
```

Comment: Hi Steve, I tried this, but I get the same result. The url of the blank white page is also just: http://localhost:3000/projects/70/project_questions/28 (no reference to project answer)

Comment: Does the answer exist?  If not,  you should be calling the new path not the edit path.

Comment: Hi Steve, yes the answer exists. I'm trying to edit it.

Comment: I'm thinking maybe it doesn't, although we think it does.  If you change `<%=singleQuestion.project_answer.try(:answer) %>` to `<%=singleQuestion.project_answer.answer %>` do you get an error on rendering?  Also in your controller try changing the set_project_question to  @project_question = ProjectQuestion.find(params[:project_question_id])

Comment: Hi Steve, strangely, that change (remove try) made the edit path work. I'm baffled as to why. This problem is now solved though, so although I don't understand why, it's fixed.

Comment: Ps, I didn't change the controller, just the view

Comment: I'm not sure why it should be fixed... if that was the only difference then that suggests `singleQuestion.project_answer.try(:answer)` doesn't load the answer even when present which suggests something's weird about the association... having noted that, I just realised you have `belongs_to project_questions` and the correct wording is `belongs_to project_question` but I don't know if that would cause the weirdness.  Anyway, glad you got it and thanks for the acceptance.

Answer (score 1):

```
edit_project_project_question_project_answer GET  /projects/:project_id/project_questions/:project_question_id/project_answers/:id/edit(.:format) project_answers#edit
```

You have to give value for `:project_id` too to get the link work.

This should work

```
<%= link_to 'Edit Answer', edit_project_project_question_project_answer_path(@project, singleQuestion, @project_answer) %>
```

Comment: The link works, but it doesnt go to the answer partial

Comment: @user2860931 Where it took you to?

Comment: just a blank white page, no application layout or anything. its weird.

Comment: that goes to a blank page too, with the same url

Comment: Probably the page is empty. Did you write any code in it?

Comment: it has render form (same as the new page). do i need to do something in the edit controller given it is being called from project question in stead of project answer?

Comment: @user2860931 The page for edit project answers is in project_questions folder or project_answers folder?

Comment: project_answers folder

Comment: it's weird because the url stops at project_questions - shouldn't it have something for answers in there too?